# Applying a filter to only show object from longer than 4 months ago In Ms-Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table named "table1" with a field called "Deployment Date" (please forgive the space). in VBA, I'm attempting to apply a filter which will only show objects deployed earlier than 4 months from the current date. here a bit of the code.

```
Dim str1 As Date
str1 = DateAdd("M", -4, Now())
str1 = "=" & str1
DoCmd.SetFilter WhereCondition:="[Deployment Date]" & "<" & Chr(34) & str1 & Chr(34)
```

Whenever ran, it will deselect all values in the "Deployment Date" Field, but still show all values inside of the field. the field is in the Long Time Format
Would know how to tweak the code to make this work? thank you all in advance.

EDIT: Updated the code, still doesn't seem to function

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Dim str1 As String
str1 = Format(Date, "Long Time")
str1 = DateAdd("M", -4, str1)
str1 = "=" & str1
DoCmd.SetFilter WhereCondition:="[Deployment Date]" & "<" & Chr(34) & str1 & Chr(34)
```

Comment: I believe you will want to remove the `=` from `str1`

Comment: Removed The `=` from `str1`, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chr(35), in MS SQL dates should be surrounded by #

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up strings and date values. Try this:

```
Dim str1 As String
str1 = Format(DateAdd("m", -4, Date), "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
DoCmd.SetFilter WhereCondition:= "[Deployment Date] < #" & str1 & "#"
```